# What do I get the druid that has everything?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, treasure

I've got a group of players in a D&D 3.5 campaign:

- a human rog3/clr1
- a human clr4
- an elven bard2/sorc2
- an elven druid4
- a dwarven fighter4

Soon they'll be playing a special Thanksgiving/Xmas game (we missed the game right after Thanksgiving and we're skipping the one that would be right after Xmas) where their characters can't die and WILL get loot.

They've been sorta role-play heavy and have gotten most of their loot through roleplay (talking down sides to a war, solving mysteries).  I try to keep my game realistic-ish, so I can't really get their WBL up to where it should be at this point.  Most of the situations they've been in would have been easily avoidable if either side had a large amount of currency to throw around, they haven't been heavily involved with people able to wield large amounts of magic (for the same reason), and I can't load them up with enough mundane equipment to make a dent in the difference.

As a reward for their hard work, their mysterious (and obviously magical) benefactor is going to send them to a party.  The idea is that powerful beings (very old dragons, gods, potent wizards, etc) hold a party every decade or so and each nominate mortals to attend.  Their sent to a small plane where all damage is nonlethal and put through a series of tests (some serious, many silly).  Essentially, they're going to get to star in YouTube videos for the gods.

As a reward for doing well, each character will get a magical item.  The potency of the magical item will be relative to how well the characters do.

The rogue will get a magical dancing dagger which (unlike normal dancing weapons) will flank her current opponent.  The enchantment bonus will depend on how well she does (going from a penalty to hit to a +2 attack).

The cleric (who is really, really, REALLY concerned with logistics) will get either a ring of sustenance, an eternal ration, a small belt of hidden pouches, or a small bag of holding.

The bard will get a simulacrum - a 'mini-me' that will back him up on his Perform checks and can keep his bard songs going while he does other things in combat.  It's differences will be in personality (going from EXACTLY like the bard and scaling up to a helpful, eager-to-please personality).

The fighter will get a dwarven waraxe that can transform into another object.  It'll start as a +1 waraxe that turns into a stepstool (and back) when you use a command word.  The highest form will be a +1 flaming waraxe that transforms into any mundane wooden equipment on use of a command word.

The munchkin in me sees these items as potential FUN, and I know my players well enough to know that they won't abuse them in game-shattering ways.

My problem is that I don't know what to get the druid.  I mean, what do you get for the class that has everything?  Is there something I can hand to a druid that is relatively similar in power to what I'm giving the rest?  What would be useful?

Edit: Thank you all for your wonderful suggestions.  The druid will get one of the following (in order of top tier to worst tier):

- Staff of Nature (based off of Dakeyras's answer, with a bit of Leezard's) 2/day it will bolster plant growth in an area (as the Enrichment ability of the spell of the same name) in a greatly reduced area.  It also has two leaves growing from the top, a holly and an oak which will (if consumed, a standard action that provokes attacks of opportunity) permit the recall of a single 1st or 2nd level spell that has already been cast (or forgotten for Summon Nature's Ally).  Leaves so used regrow in 1d4-1 days.
- Tent of Solace (based off of MACN's answer) a tent that serves as a *Tiny Hut* for the druid and her animal companion, providing each with water (but not food).  1/day the druid's animal companion may enter or leave the tent even if it is not set up.
- Collar of Enhancement (inspired by Phill.Zitt) a collar that, when worn, allows an animal companion to treat their druid master as if they were 1 druid level higher when determining animal companion enhancements.
- Nature's bow - a bow that creates its own arrows (1/round) when drawn and grants each arrow a random bonus:

  1. +1 attack/damage
  2. +1d6 cold damage
  3. Arrow grows thorns on hit, causing 1 damage/round until removed.  Removal does and additional 1d6 damage
  4. Successful hit causes no damage, target goes to *sleep* (Fort save DC 10+attacker's Wisdom bonus to resist)
  5. Successful hit deals no damage, target must pass a DC 18 Reflex save or become Entangled (as if hit by a tanglefoot bag)
  6. Successful hit deals no damage, target must pass a DC 15 + attacker's WIS modifier Will save or become passive, non-hostile, and lose their DEX bonus to AC for 1d4-1 rounds.

They're a bit more potent than I'd hand to a more experienced player, but they all have immediate useful effects, and they should enhance the game while remaining fun.

Comment: Answers are not for comments. They have been deleted because we're starting to get a plague of them around here.

Comment: This question is basically asking for shopping advice. I thought those are frowned upon everywhere on StackExchange...

Comment: @AnsisMalins Because so much about RPG advice is inherently subjective we can't rule out some of the more subjective types of questions, but you're right: this is a recommendation question, and to keep those in the realm of answerable we have [some pretty strict requirements that recommendation answers need to adhere to](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic), to make such questions work in the format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something fun and interesting for the druid could be a custom magic item called *Staff of Plant Growth* or something similar, that has X charges per day (maybe depends on how well she does) and can create grass, small trees, or some other form of plant life. It follows the pattern you've established so far, namely that it's partially class-specific, and this could be useful in combat (heavy plant life could be used as (partial) cover) or good fun if roleplayed well - she could use it to cover tracks, hide items, and scare commoners (or even convince them she's the messiah!), while being generally magical.

I'm mostly suggesting this because it's fairly simple, quite versatile, interesting to roleplay with, and you've not shown much indication that you want something too balanced for the characters (in terms of equal cost). Also, unique magic items are always more interesting, I find.

Other cool unique items I've used in the past include a small, portable one-way dimensional hole to the Elemental Plane of Fire that was effectively a firelighter, a quill that writes down people's thoughts within a ten-foot radius, and a ten-foot pole that turns into a match and back again when a command word is uttered. They range from quite handy to very powerful, but in my campaign they were all moderately useful at the point where the players got them. You should be very careful about accepting advice on item balance in your games, especially if they're not combat-heavy.

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer, though there were some awesome suggestions from other people.

Answer (score 5):

You can give the druid a body-suit type of belt (that essentially passes over his back, waist etc around his torso) that links his worn gear. Think of leather red strips linked with metal rings.

Depending on how good he did and the quality of the magic belt, it will allow him to gain the benefits of one, two or three magic items worn in his human form even when he uses his Wild Shape ability.

Unique, interesting and synergizes with his core abilities. Moreover it's not something he can have in any other way from any book (that I know of). You can name it Belt of Natural Symbiosis.

Comment: Would the session level them up?

Answer (score 5):

You could give him a camping tent that, once properly set up, acts like a [door](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesMagnificentMansion.htm) to a a small demiplane accessible only by the druid and his pet. Initially, that space would look like a nest built inside a thick bramble patch, behaving like a [tiny hut](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/tinyHut.htm), but offering only the minimal space needed for the druid and his pet to rest in a straw mattress over packed earth.

It would evolve by growing in size, and gaining elements like:

- A spring of drinkable water, bushes loaded with berries, and other
  boons of nature that the druid would use for sustenance.
- Elements needed to cover animal companions needs with things like
  plentiful grass for herbivores, small game for carnivores and even a
  pond for aquatic companions.

Its aspect would slowly change from its dull and uncomfortable initial appearance to what would look like a clearing in a thick forest, like what is described [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/groveOfRespite.html). Its final form would be quite large, looking like a beautiful Druidic grove, circle of stones included.

Apart from offering refuge, sustenance, and storage, it would allow the druid several advantages:

- The druid needs to set up the tent completely to use it, but can use
  it while it dismantled as if were it a [portable hole](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aPortable_Hole) to allow his animal companion to enter and exit
  from the refuge. This way, he could easily carry his animal companion to
  places where it could not go, or the druid would not be allowed to go
  with him:

  > **City guard:** *I mean no offence, sir, but I really cannot allow you
  >   inside  with that animal.*
  >
  > **Druid:** *Why?, it is inoffensive!.*
  >
  > **City guard:** *Maybe sir, but the guard captain would hang me
  >   from the nearest tree if I allow that dire tiger in the king's palace.*
- When the pet receives damage that would kill it, he is instead teleported to
  the refuge and left at 0 HP, stabilized. It could not leave the refuge
  for 24 hours or until fully healed, whatever happens before.
- In essence, the refuge is the true magical "item", born as a expression of
  the druid connection to nature, while the  tent is merely a link to
  it. If the  tent is lost or destroyed, the druid can recreate it by
  crafting a mundane replica and performing a lengthy but otherwise
  inexpensive ritual to attune it to the refuge. Of course, should he ever lose his status as a druid, he would be unable to access the refuge until he atones.
- Given time, it would develop elements like trees of rare wood,
  patches of special herbs and other exotic supplies suitable to be used
  as crafting material for magic items. This would work as a periodic allowance
  that can only be expended in creating magic items.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of ideas for you

- An animal sidekick; a friendly animal (maybe magical?) or construct or a [figurine of wonderous power](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aFigurine_of_Wondrous_Power) that has minor contacts and powers
- Something that gives them the ability to speak with plants
- There's some pathfinder based ideas for druids [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2i8t0?Druid-magic-items), which are similar to 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

I personally give gifts based on how the player plays the character.

What is the most interesting facet of druid for this player? Is it the spell casting? The shape-shifting? The companion?

Play to the facet of druid that the player likes best and build around that. If the player doesn't really have a preference, I would also consider treasures that boost or reduce tactical options depending on how much the player enjoys making tactical decisions.

As an example, what if you gave the character an item that dampens spellcasting while shape-shifted in return for increased shape-shifting abilities? Would the player enjoy the nuances of that tactical decision?

You could create a vest that increases effective druid level by 2 for the purposes of shifting, but reduces it by 2 for the purposes of spellcasting. You could even make it a transformation effect that takes a full round action to increase on-the-spot tactical complexity.

In my experience, satisfying players is more important than satisfying characters.

Comment: The big problem is that the druid's player is new to the system and new to the group.  She doesn't have a good feel for the character yet and I don't have a good feel for her yet.  For everyone else, the choices are easy.

Comment: Two things: At fourth level, druid do not have Wild Shape. Second, while in Wild Shape, druids cannot cast any spell with a verbal component because they can only speak natural animal sounds of whatever they Shaped into. Additionally, Spellcasting is almost always more powerful than Shaping, so the above mentioned vest would be a terribly underpowered idea.

Comment: @Jeff Then I would recommend going with a treasure that reduces or maintains complexity. If the character is very new a treasure from one of the books that she can reference readily may be the best option. Maybe a sentient but traditional item (talking wisdom amulet?) would be a safe bet?

Comment: An amulet with a +2 bonus to wisdom that gives advice on occasion would be great for a new player.

Answer (score 3):

Some items/other things that you may find to be of interest:

- "OF DOOM"
  A magical booming voice adds "OF DOOM" to everything where it might apply.    "The villager replies, 'you will find the magic fountain-OF DOOM-by going down the path-OF DOOM-over that way.'", or "Can you toss me a rope-OF DOOM-?", or even "The seer tells you, 'if you go to the castle-OF DOOM-you will meet your doom-OF DOOM'".
  Not exactly useful, but definitely fun, at least for a little while.
- Magical ropes are always nice, you can never have too much magic rope.
- Sack of Preparedness - If you can name it, it has it (just not all at once though). You can pull arbitrary items out of it. Ability to take items out is restored by putting the item(s) currently withdrawn back in, or regenerated over time if those items are destroyed/lost etc. This in particular would be a good fit for your druid. While it is not an outright combat bonus, it can be used in a way that can augment combat extremely well.
- Box of Television - Shows images of things happening elsewhere in the world. A second smaller box with a number of raised knobs seems to be able to control it when the knobs are pressed inward.

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is that I don't know what to get the druid. I mean, what do you get for the class that has everything? Is there something I can hand to a druid that is relatively similar in power to what I'm giving the rest? What would be useful?

For a durid I would go with a magic staff (or cane if you like) that looks like a gnared branch complete with a few leaves growing form the top.  Some of these leaves would have magic properties usable by pucking the leaf and using it.  In some cases that means eating it or using it to make a tea.  In other cases, just blow or flick it toward the target.  There could be any number of leaves you like making it scalable like the other items and they regrow over time.  How long the leaves take to regrow could also be a scalable element.  You could also tie the leaf effect to the type of leaf for flavor.

Any number of effects are possible, just let your imagination run with it.  Here are some suggestion, but you should make your own list that works for your game.

- Add one extra first level spell for the day, holly leaf
- Add one extra second level spell for the day, oak leaf
- Add one extra third level spell for the day, maple leaf
- For the next hour, grant the druid special abilities as if they are one level higher than they are, hickory leaf

Answer (score 2):

> The rogue will get a magical dancing dagger which (unlike normal dancing weapons) will flank her current opponent. The enchantment bonus will depend on how well she does (going from a penalty to hit to a +2 attack).

Avoid a penalty as much as possible. By RAW (and someone correct me on this) the only way for and item to have any sort of a penalty to rolls is to have it be a cursed item, with all of the headaches that entails.

> The cleric (who is really, really, REALLY concerned with logistics) will get either a ring of sustenance, an eternal ration, a small belt of hidden pouches, or a small bag of holding.

Avoid ring of sustenance on this one - it only works for the person wearing it, and it takes some time to attune (one week). If the party doesn't already have a bag of holding, they need one.

> The fighter will get a dwarven waraxe that can transform into another object. It'll start as a +1 waraxe that turns into a stepstool (and back) when you use a command word. The highest form will be a +1 flaming waraxe that transforms into any mundane wooden equipment on use of a command word.

A step stool? Meh, to me. Perhaps it makes sense in context.

> My problem is that I don't know what to get the druid. I mean, what do you get for the class that has everything? Is there something I can hand to a druid that is relatively similar in power to what I'm giving the rest? What would be useful?

So far, the 'power level' of items that you are handing out it is a bit... wonky:

1. Rogue - flanking dancing weapon. pretty good, spend an action to set it loose, automatic sneak attacks for X rounds until she has to pick it up and reactivate it. Powerful.
2. Cleric - Unless it's a bag of holding, pretty much crap.
3. Bard - Bonus to perform, and can sustain in combat? Powerful.
4. Fighter - +1 waraxe, good. can turn into mundane objects... useful, but meh to me. If the party doesn't have a full set of whatever adventuring gear they need, maybe they need more straight-cash-gold to pick some up.

As for the druid, try to tie something into what she likes to do. If she uses her animal companion a bunch, give her an item that bumps her effective druid level up when [determining companion bonuses](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#theDruidsAnimalCompanion), or a collar that goes on the companion to advance it, or an inherent(!) bonus that treats her level as X higher when [determining what animals she can select](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#alternativeAnimalCompanions).

If she is more spell-heavy, give her something to reflect that - A [Pearl of Power](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#pearlofPower), but for druids.

Or, in keeping with the Roleplay-focus, talk with the player and see if they have any ideas for a magic item that would fit the character better than some mechanical bonus.

Comment: I think you misunderstand just HOW MUCH the cleric is on about logistics.  And he's asked for a RoS multiple times.  The stepstool is part of an ongoing joke about the dwarf's height (and she'd only get it if she gets the lowest-tier of prizes).

Comment: This would be improved and be more on-topic if all but the last three paragraphs were removed. (The question didn't ask for advice about the other stuff, but provided it as a examples to follow for what is a good suggestion for the druid. Critical analysis of a rubric is the opposite of what one is supposed to do with a rubric.)

Comment: @Christian Generally speaking, we aim to answer the *question* being asked, not just the title at the top of the page. People, as a rule, are terrible at writing titles. We very often rewrite titles to better represent the actual question posted.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I will admit to maybe not reading the question all the way through, and guessing on a couple parts. I agree that the answer may be more on topic if cut down to the last three paragraphs, though I disagree that this will improve the answer. ( If a rubric is a bad rubric, maybe it needs a bit of critical analysis. Ever seen a rubric where the percentages don't add up 100%? )

Answer (score 1):

A dowsing rod that effectively allows them to use the Maximize Spell feat, but only for Summon Nature's Ally spells.  Performance by the character could reduce the number of levels higher the spell is treated as and/or the number of levels of the spell it applies for (IE can maximize the number of level 1 critters for SNA 2 only, or for critters level 3 and down, etc.)

> Maximize Spell [Metamagic]
>   Benefit
>
> All variable, numeric effects of a spell modified by this feat are maximized. Saving throws and opposed rolls are not affected, nor are spells without random variables. A maximized spell uses up a spell slot three levels higher than the spell’s actual level.
>
> An empowered, maximized spell gains the separate benefits of each feat: the maximum result plus one-half the normally rolled result.

Answer (score 1):

**Necklace of Lethe**, a simple looking necklace with some(1d4) bright blue-pulsating pearls attached on it. When the wearer is struck with a deadly blow when in true form, one of the pearls absorbs the damage and turns into a black pearl(giving a huge energy surge to the last attacker, damaging+paralyzing for 1d6 rounds + making the attacker forget the last 1d4 months of experience/memories or just a 1d4 level drain if its simpler).

Each black pearl on the necklace is a boost to a stat or another attribute when wearer is in animal form. (like giving another hit-die to top of his wolf/bear form or giving a random stat like wisdom or strength) in a "Whatever doesnt kill you makes you stronger" style.

When all pearls become black pearls, the wild shape becomes a climatic one (like if wolf becomes winter wolf with some cold subtype supernatural abilities)

It is said that this necklace was created by a wizard to protect two of her friends from eachother.

**Ever-Pulsing Heart of the Failed**, a very dark heart beating itself indefinitely and has some lavatic-bright-red scars on it, feels warm when you approach but cold to the touch. Legend says it was created by the ones who created Tarrasque, main purpose was having a  truly regenerative and godlike powers, this heart was such a shame for one of the creators that is thrown out of clouds. Someone inevitably has found it but heart traveled within many bodies and still has some effect. It is said that, whoever touches it, the heart shrinks/grows to the same size of the heart of that person, finally diving into skin of that person and replacing his/her heart with itself. If wearer dies by accident, heart remains alive near the rotting corpse. Regenerates +1 hp for every 4 levels of the owner per 1d4 turns. Gives bonus to saves against poison equal to hit-die number, disease and system-shock criticals, gives endurance feat(if already taken this feat, just gives +1 fortitude save bonus). Regenerates only in wild shape if you think this is too powerful.

To kill the heart, a "wish" spell is needed when its hp is -10. Total HP of heart is 50. The heart must be detached from body to make this.

**Focus Diamond**, triples a spell's cast range. Once per day. Needs to be charged when resting. Doesnt stack with other metamagic feats. Although looking like a dimamond, it is not. Once used in Battle of Sarcrag by a mage but lost. It has a very sharp and thing bottom part so can be easily fit on tip of a wand.

**Talisman of Nature's Call**, wearer has the ability of charging it with any spell. In return, once a day, has the ability of calling local animals to help as many as hit-die of the wearer, each animal can be maximum of 1 hit-die per level of the spell charges it.
Animals attack every non-natural creature except the wearer. Incident happens for a maximum of 2d10+wisdom turns. Then animals go back to their life. If wearer is level 7 and spell she charges is level 1, then 7 animals come for help each having 1 hit-die.  If the wearer calls 1-hit-die then they be bees that stings enemies.

If there are no natural-beasts around, wearer makes a wisdom-check against DC23. If she does not fail, then a huge magical roc is called from very far corner of the vicinity. It has hit-die equal to (wearer's level)+(wisdom of wearer)+1d4. It reaches to battlefield after 3d10-wisdom turns. Fights to death. Does attack only enemies.  Of course if total hit-die is small then roc is not huge.

Can try DC30 for a purpe-worm.(attacks everything, even the wearer)

Mother Earth's gift to guardians of forests.

**Soul Stone**, when an enemy(who has a soul) is killed by owner(in wild form) of this artifact, has %5 chance to accumulate it on top of other souls in the stone(max 8). This power can be used later to strengthen a magic as if done with a bonus to caster-level equal to souls used(1d4-1 souls used,). If a ninth soul is tried to be accumulated, soul stone releases all souls, making a 8d6 negative energy damage to everyone in a 30-ft radius except the wearer in wild form. Then stone fades to black, becomes unusable until a finger of death is cast on the wearer. Each soul it has makes it brighter.

**Incandescent Blue Ioun Stone**, gives +2 to wisdom.

**True name of a devil**, if there is a slightest chance of contact with one of these, better to know a name beforehand. Better not to tell anyone. From a tome of magic or some simple book of a dead wizard who knows things.

Comment: Every single one of these is hideously powerful (excepting the Ioun Stone) and/or requires Wild Shape, which the druid doesn't have yet.

Comment: @Jeff what about weakened versions of Lethe or Nature's Call ? Like having a single pearl for one and having reduced hit-die of the other. By the way, a druid would love a tree that can talk to her and give some fruits that boost wisdom or something else :)